# Merge two c# object(json) lists as parent child

Tags: c#, json, linq, collections

I have a json string which looks as below:

```
[
  {
     "id": 1,
    "title": "Hello"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "test"
  }
]


[
  {
     "id": 1,
    "parentId": 1,
    "prop1": "sdsdsdt",
    "prop1l": "3dsdsd",
    "v": "fsssd sd"
  },
   {
     "id": 2,
    "parentId": 1,
    "prop1": "sdsdsdt",
    "prop1l": "3dsdsd",
    "v": "fsssd sd"
  },
    {
     "id": 3,
    "parentId": 2,
    "prop1": "sdsdsdt",
    "prop2": "3dsdsd",
    "prop3": "fsssd sd"
  }
]
```

I can serialize it into two classes (list) as below:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}


public class Child
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create third collection where I can merge children under parent object. I know I can do with for loop in parent and look for children for parentId in Child. I wonder if there is a better way? So I can get these as below list:

```
public class Merged
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public list<Child> children{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You should look into using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to map parent and children into a Merged object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `LINQ` just with `Select` method:

```
var mergedList = parentList
.Select(p=> new Merged
{
  id = p.Id, 
  title = p.title, 
  children = childList.Where(c=>c.parentId == p.id).ToList()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After you serialized your collections, you can use `LINQ` `GroupBy` method:

```
var parentList = new List<Parent>(); //your serialized parent list
var childList = new List<Child>(); //your serialized child list

var mergedList = parentList
    .GroupJoin(
        childList, p => p.id, ch => ch.parentId, (p, ch) => new Merged {
            id = p.id, 
            title = p.title,
            children = ch.ToList()      
        })
    .ToList();
```